# What is the best way to load a properties file on JAVA

Tags: java, file, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to read properties file in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428549/best-way-to-read-properties-file-in-java)

I want to know what is the best way to load a .propertie file on JAVA,I was looking around here but cant find what i look.The thing is what is the best way for load it.
I use it for a game Develop.

Regards,
Migue

Comment: What's wrong with using the `Properties` class?

Answer (score 8):

How about that?

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("example.properties"));
properties.load(stream);
stream.close();
String sprache = properties.getProperty("lang");
```

Comment: Upvote for providing example on how to obtain a property once it's loaded.

Comment: One thing to note is that the Properties class by default supports only ISO 8859-1 which might be an issue if you are going to support unicode characters. But you can always override the default implementation to natively support unicode characters.

Comment: @dinukadev: with Java7 you can use a `Reader` to load the properties. That way UTF-8 is also supported. You can include unicode characters by escaping them (e.g. `\u201d`) in an ISO encoded properties file. The NetBeans properties editor will do that automatically.

Comment: Hey thx for the tip. I did not know that actually.. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties");
properties.load(inputStream);
inputStream.close();
```

The file path of your foo.properties will need to change if it's not in the same package as the class loading the properties file. If the .properties file is in `com.example.properties.here` for example, then use the following file path for the `InputStream`.

`InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/properties/here/foo.properties");`

Comment: I test it and it get me the same time like the other one,but i think Buffered is better than Normal InputStream. Please help me with this query. Regards,

Comment: BufferedReader is generally more efficient, since (as its name implies) buffers what it reads, reducing the low-level I/O operations required. However, in the example I provided, getClass().getResourceAsStream() returns an InputStream, thus you need to use it. Based on that, I would agree that PKeidel's answer is the better one since it uses the more efficient BufferedReader.

Comment: Thanks for solve me the query!

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with UTF-8 and automatically discover properties in the classpath.

```java
public class I18nBean {

private ResourceBundle resourceBundle;

private static I18nBean instance = new I18nBean("app"); //app.properties

public static I18nBean getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

/**
    @param propertyFileName - without extension, i.e 
    if you have app.properties, pass "app"
*/
private I18nBean(String propertyFileName) {
    resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(propertyFileName);
}

public String get(String key) {
    try {
        String foundString = resourceBundle.getString(key);
        return convertToUTF8(foundString);
    } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        return "";
    }
}

private String convertToUTF8(String str)  {
    try {
        return new String(str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return str; //not real case
    }
}
```

}

Usage:

```
I18nBean i18nBean = I18nBean.getInstance();
i18nBean.get("application.name");
```

Comment: I think this is what will help me more cauz i will have to log ascii packets for the game.